# Set linespread in algorithm environments

Tags: spacing, algorithms

My algorithms are really complicated and I want to `\onehalfspace` their lines to make them more readable, while keeping the rest of the document `singlespace`. How can I do this so it will automatically do it for all my `algorithm`environments?

Comment: In the absence of a MWE, try this: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\onehalfspacing}`  Change `algorithmic` with your environment.

Comment: What package do you use to set your algorithms?

Comment: @HarishKumar please post your answer, it worked for me

Comment: @RenéG Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the linespacing by inserting `\onehalfspacing` soon after the `algorithm` environment. If this is wanted for all such instances, you may use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox` like

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\onehalfspacing}
```

in the preamble.

Obligatory code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\onehalfspacing}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}%[H]
  \caption{Example}
    \label{lst:d}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE ...
        \STATE ...
        \FORALL{$D_i$ in $PC$}
            \STATE ...
            \STATE ...
            \IF{$D_i$ contains a disjunction}
                \STATE Split $D_i$ at every disjunction
                \STATE Transform every splitted part into a $RPTP$ and store it in $rptp$
            \ELSE
                \STATE Transform $D_i$ into a $RPTP$ and store it in $rptp$
            \ENDIF
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]